# Password verification

Tags: java

I need my code to check the password and one of the letters in password should be in upper case. When user is entering. 
Please assist.

```
        int digcheck=0,charcheck=0,symbcheck=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < passwordraw.length(); i++) {
             if (Character.isDigit(passwordraw.charAt(i)))
             {
                digcheck++; 
             }
             else if(Character.isLetter(passwordraw.charAt(i))) 
             {
                charcheck++;
             }
             else
             {
                symbcheck++; 
             }              
        }
        if(digcheck<3)
        {
            digcheck=0;
            throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast three(3) digits.");
        }else if(charcheck<5)
        {
            charcheck=0;
            throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast five(5) alpha.");
        }
        else if(symbcheck<1)
        {
            symbcheck=0;
            throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast one(1) symbol.");
        }
```

Comment: so what is the problem you have with solving this task?

Comment: offtopic, but it will be useful, if you decide to develop real software. Do not use excess exclamation signs and do not use word `must` in that context. It is just an error, not an asteroid which is going to destroy the Earth.

Comment: use regEx instead .. you would have much fine grained control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int digcheck=0,charcheck=0,symbcheck=0,caseCheck=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordraw.length(); i++) {
         if (Character.isDigit(passwordraw.charAt(i)))
         {
            digcheck++; 
         }
         else if(Character.isLetter(passwordraw.charAt(i))) 
         {
            charcheck++;
            if(Character.isUpperCase(passwordraw.charAt(i))){
              caseCheck++;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            symbcheck++; 
         }              
    }
    if(digcheck<3)
    {
        digcheck=0;
        throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast three(3) digits.");
    }else if(charcheck<5)
    {
        charcheck=0;
        throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast five(5) alpha.");
    }
    else if(symbcheck<1)
    {
        symbcheck=0;
        throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast one(1) symbol.");
    }
   else if(caseCheck<1)
    {
        caseCheck=0;
        throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast one(1) Uppercase Letter.");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use regex.

make the password match with `.*[A-Z]+.*`
this will make your password have at least one uppercase char

[EDIT]
you can also use regex to find the other restrictions.

to have at least 3 digits you can use this regex

```
.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*
```

this will match anything plus 1 digit, more anything, at least one digit, and so on.. you can have the similar regex to other validations, please net us know if you need help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use nested `else-if` as your conditions are different. If a condition is true than other two will be skipped.

```
   if(digcheck<3){
        digcheck=0;
        throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast three(3) digits.");
    }

   if(charcheck<5){
        charcheck=0;
        throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast five(5) alpha.");
    }

   if(symbcheck<1){
        symbcheck=0;
        throw new OBSSecurityException("INVALID PASSWORD! Must have atleast one(1) symbol.");
    }
```

Comment: Effectively there is no change upon using else-if ladder or simple if, since the execution is redirected upon `throw new Exception()`

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that checks if password contains at least one upper case character:

```
public boolean containsAtLeastOneUpperCase(String password) {
    for(Character c : password.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```